# Django Tastypie always returning 401 unauthorized

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, tastypie

I'm using ajax requests to my tastypie resources, but even if I use SessionAuthentication() and DjangoAuthorization(), it gets always 401.

resources.py

```
class EventsResource(ModelResource):

user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Event.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'events'
        filtering = {'start': ALL,
                     'end':ALL
                     }
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post','put', 'patch']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        include_resource_uri = True
        limit = 0
        always_return_data = True
```

This is a resource for a calendar, so I have a Event Model, and my ajax requests are in a javascript file loaded in django-admin; I also checked if requests headers had csrf token and session id, but it doesn't work.

```
.ajax({
                    url:  event.resource_uri,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; encode=UTF-8',
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    success: function () {
                        $calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        $calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        $('#modal-confirm').modal('hide');
                        showmsg('Evento eliminato correttamente', 'warning');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `SessionAuthentication` but have not provided a CSRF token header (I see you checked for it, but it doesn't appear in your code).

Include the `{% csrf_token %}` tag somewhere in the page containing your JavaScript, then modify your AJAX method to set a `X-CSRF-Token` header using the `beforeSend` option:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  event.resource_uri,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; encode=UTF-8',
    type: 'DELETE',
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());
    },
    success: function () {
        $calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        $('#modal-confirm').modal('hide');
        showmsg('Evento eliminato correttamente', 'warning');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the CSRF token in as POST data with every POST request. The recommended source of the CSRF token is from cookies, like this:

```
getCookie: function(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = $.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Then, you’ll set the header on your AJAX request like this:

```
var csrftoken = this.getCookie('csrftoken');
//Use Setup prior or use the beforeSend on the fly 
/*$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
});*/
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/my/uri/",
    data: {"any": "thing"},
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("Weeey") ;
    }
});
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax